# Project Target Framework Not Installed (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am facing this issue with Visual Studio 2013. I got a Visual Studio solution from my colleague. When I open the solution, projects are not loading. When I tried to reload the project by selecting project. I got a below attached 
[window prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqmNB.jpg) alert.

-When I am selecting first radio button then project is loading. But If again I am re-opening the solution then I am getting the some problem.

I followed below steps to solve the problem

1. Selected second radio button (Download the targeting pack for ".NetFramework, Version=v4.5". The project will not change. After clicking the OK button got
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12485&pver=12&sbp=TargetPackMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=.NETFramework,Version=v4.5 page.
   Selected Visaul Studio 2013 but there .NET Framework 4.5 is not supporting Visual Studio 2013. So I downloaded .NET Framework 4.5.2 and installed. But problem didn't get solve.
2. I repaired the  Visual Studio 2013. But Still same problem.

Can you please suggest me how I can fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Finally I *uninstalled* the visual studio 2013 and I *re-installed* visual studio 2013. Now all issue gone away. Thanks